# Spring: Check present interceptors

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Is there a way to check which interceptors are present for the current method?

An example: if I am debugging the following method (any line in the method)

```
@OpenSession
@Transactional
public void run() {
    // do something ... 
}
```

is it possible to check that the @OpenSession and @Transactional interceptors are actually doing their work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: set a breakpoint in one of the Aspect classes.

You can debug Spring AOP with any IDE and real aspectj with Eclipse's [AspectJ Developer Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) (which are included in the [SpringSource ToolSuite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts).

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a test (Test driven Design) that verify the side effect of the annotation you want to have.

The test should fail without annotation, and should pass if the annotation trigger the action you need.

Comment: I don't know. If you do that, you are testing the framework. That should be left to those who develop the framework.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: I don't think so: I don't want to test that the annotations work (in a Whitebox way). I want to test that the function works in a black box test. And to pass this test, one way is, that the function use the framework functionality.